# Are "Case Postale" and "Boîte Postale" interchangeable?

Tags: usage, québec

Looking at addresses, I've run into both **CP** or **Case Postale**, as well as **BP**, or **Boîte Postale**.  Are the terms interchangeable?  Does this vary by country?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case Postale (CP) is used in Canada and in Switzerland.
Boite Postale (BP) is used in France and in Belgium.

They represent the same service, i.e. a locker (box) situated on the premises of a post office building and that an individual rents to have his mail addressed to.

Answer (score 7):

They are not interchangeable in France :

- "***CP***" does not mean "*Case Postale*" or "*Casier Postal*" but "***Code*** Postal". It is a 5-digits code indicating places where mails have to go in the country. For further informations about it, you can refer to Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_France
- "***BP***", which means "*Boîte Postale*", is just a classic post-office box.

Answer (score 5):

*Case postale* and *boîte postale* are synonyms and are both correct. What is similar but improper in that sense is *casier postal*.

*Le Petit Robert* lists *case postale* as a regionalism, so it is probably better to use *boîte postale* in France, but it is used elsewhere. For example, Canada Post recommends using *case postale*, but both are accepted.

Comment: +1, in France, I never heard *case postale* (but I would understand it), but I'm not surprised if you say it's correct. I'd use ***boîte postale***.

Comment: Could you give more information about casier postal?

Comment: @Zoot: as Kareen says *casier postal*  is an improper (wrong) use of Case Postale, so there is no further information to be given about it!

Comment: @Laure: Then it should read "what is similar in that sense but improper", I was also confused.

Answer (score 1):

"Case postale" has been used for at least some years by Canada Post as its official term for "post office box" in French (not entirely sure why they changed though), although "boîte postale" remains in common use.